# ManytoMany Relation between 3 tables Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables with Models all belongToMany related with each other:

- Batchyear
- Grade
- Student

A student may attend many `batchyears`, and will be have many `grades`, and each `grade` have many `students`.

How to get the relationship via Eloquent so that a `student` is in a certain `grade` in a certain `batchyear`?

```
class Batch extends Model
{
    public $guarded = [];

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
    }

    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Grade::class);
    }
}
```

and here is grade

```
class Grade extends Model
{
    public $guarded = [];

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
    }

    public function batches(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Batch::class);
    }
}
```

and students

```
class Student extends Model
{
    public $guarded = [];

    public function batches()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Batch::class)->withPivot(['batch_id']);
    }

    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Grade::class);
    }
}
```

tables students . batches. grades. batch_student, batch_grade. and grade_student . dont solve the problem. if I select a grades student It shows all students even who are in previous batch in this grade. need a table like student_grade_batch. so 3 foreign keys.

Comment: Please can you show the code you have where you want to perform the query i.e. how are you getting the `Batch` and `Grade` to find out which `Student`s to get?

Comment: I want to show students who belong to a certain grade of a certain batch. selctect batch which have many grades select a grade and show its students but the same grade belongs to another batch so showing that students also